try generate a list-item using map method it works but it is not working with parameter function
function List() {

    const fruits = [
        { id: 1, name: 'orange', calories: 67 },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana', calories: 63 },
        { id: 3, name: 'pineapple', calories: 87 },
        { id: 4, name: 'coconut', calories: 69 },
        { id: 5, name: 'kiwi', calories: 56 },
        { id: 6, name: 'guava', calories: 36 }
    ]

     
    const fruitlist = fruits.map(fruit => <li key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name} {fruit.calories}</li>)
     return (<ol>{fruitlist}</ol>)

}

export default List

function List() {

    const fruits = [
        { id: 1, name: 'orange', calories: 67 },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana', calories: 63 },
        { id: 3, name: 'pineapple', calories: 87 },
        { id: 4, name: 'coconut', calories: 69 },
        { id: 5, name: 'kiwi', calories: 56 },
        { id: 6, name: 'guava', calories: 36 }
    ]

// this is not working 

    let fruitslist = fruits.map(function (frt) {
        <li  key={fruit.id}>{frt.name}{frt.calories}</li>
    })
    return (<ol>{fruitlist}</ol>)
}

export default List


Because you're using curly braces for your map function you need to explicitly return from inside it: return <li  key={fruit.id}>{frt.name}{frt.calories}</li>.

@Andy. Thanks mate for your solution, it is still not showing/working anything

You also have some typos. fruitslist should be fruitlist and fruit.id should be frt.id. Both of those errors should have appeared in your developer console.

leave the typos  please provide me solution

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

"not working" is not a good problem description. You got the wrong result, an error (which?), an infinite loop? What were the results of your debugging session? Above several problems have been identified, but apparently you have not yet applied the fixes for the typos. Above some volunteers have analysed your code and found issues. Some minimal effort is expected from your side...

function List() {
const fruits = [
    { id: 1, name: 'orange', calories: 67 },
]

// working
const fruitlist = fruits.map(fruit => {fruit.name} {fruit.calories})
return ({fruitlist})
// Not working
let fruitslist = fruits.map(function (frt) {
{frt.name}{frt.calories}
return ({fruitslist})
})
return ({fruitslist})
// Error : Cannot access 'fruitslist' before initialization
}
export default List

Pasting multi-line code in the comment section doesn't format well. Please update your question using the edit link below it. Make sure to also elaborate on the problem description (what goes wrong, what have you debugged, ...)

@trincot please check i have elaborated the question problemand give me a solution mate thanks

Did you read my comment? I don't see any edit you made to the question. The body of your question just has two code blocks with a comment "This is not working". If you hope to get a useful answer, please update your question. You can get some help from How to Ask a good question, and take the tour.


Since your map callback uses curly braces (not parentheses) you must explicitly return a value from it using the return keyword.

You call your mapped data fruitslist (plural) but you're trying to use a variable called fruitlist (singular). Fix one or the other.

In your map callback you're trying to use fruit.id but the argument is called frt. Similarly to frt.name and frt.calories rename it frt.id.




const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const fruits = [
      { id: 1, name: 'orange', calories: 67 },
      { id: 2, name: 'banana', calories: 63 },
      { id: 3, name: 'pineapple', calories: 87 },
      { id: 4, name: 'coconut', calories: 69 },
      { id: 5, name: 'kiwi', calories: 56 },
      { id: 6, name: 'guava', calories: 36 }
  ];

  const fruitslist = fruits.map(function (frt) {
    return <li key={frt.id}>{frt.name}{frt.calories}</li>;
  });

  return <ol>{fruitslist}</ol>;

}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



